# Finding services and processes

Tags: powershell

Good afternoon,

I am searching for help here as I've exhausted all the resources. It seems that my powershell skills don't serve me well on this task.

I have to complete four tasks, as follows:

1. List the running processes.
2. List the running services and their PID.
3. For each process found, check if there is a service and list the services and the PID.
4. List the processes that don't have services and their PID.

For 1 and 2 it's quite, simple, I've used:

1. `get-process`
2. `get-wmiobject -class Win32_process | select Name, ProcessID`

The difficulty is at 3 and 4, as I don't know how to relate the running processes with their existing / non-existing services.

Thank you in advance for any help, advice, or code.

Comment: It looks like a colleague of you just asked that same question, you should use the search box above to find the answer given.

Comment: Where is the code mate? Please share your effort what you have tried?

Comment: What are [you up to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? This sounds a bit strange task, so maybe there's better a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something such as:

```
$processes = Get-Process
$services = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service
foreach ( $process in $processes ) {
  if ( $process.Id -eq 0 ) {
    continue
  }
  $service = $services | Where-Object { $_.ProcessId -eq $process.Id }
  if ( $service ) {
    $isService = $true
    $serviceNames = $service.Name -as [Array]
  }
  else {
    $isService = $false
    $serviceNames = @($null)
  }
  foreach ( $serviceName in $serviceNames ) {
    [PSCustomObject] @{
      "ProcessId"   = $process.Id
      "ProcessName" = $process.Name
      "Service"     = $isService
      "ServiceName" = $serviceName
    }
  }
}
```

(There are probably faster ways, but this should give you an idea.)